# Why the value in session varible in trigger becomes null in mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers, session-variables

I Created Trigger in mysql, though there is no errors in the trigger value  for the season variable is not calculated.

Trigger:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER `Total_orders` BEFORE INSERT ON Orders
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   DECLARE sum Float;
   SET sum = sum + Amount;
   SET @Sum = sum;
END$$
```

Output is:

```bsh
select @Sum;
+------+
| @Sum |
+------+
| NULL |
+------+
```

Comment: Just declaring it, is set to NULL,NULL+Amount still is NULL

Comment: @Mihai Can you me example,how to declare as NULL

Comment: JUSt by declaring it a variable is already ste to NULL,after you declare it SET it to 0 or whatever do you need

Comment: @Mihai is this way
`DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE Total(IN ProductName text(25))
BEGIN
DECLARE sum=0 Float ;
SET sum=sum + New.Amount;
Set @Sum=0;
Set @Sum=sum;
END //
DELIMITER ;`

Comment: SET sum=0;SET sum=sum + New.Amount;Set @Sum=sum